# Want to generate a report and need to apply 6-8 filters on data

Tags: sql, oracle, report

I have to group by age and need to show results on the basis of sum of bonus, gender, is_permanent and then department. What will be the sql query for this kind of report.

Department 
       - Is Permanent
             - gender
                  - monthly bonus
                  - Quarterly bonus
                  - Yearly Bonus

All the data should come from EMPLOYEE table, looks like

```
empid| DOB     | gender| annual_bonus| monthly_bonus| quarterly_bonus| Is_Permanent| Department|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101  | 31122002| M     | 100        | 300          | 600            | No           | Admin|
102  | 31122002| f     | 120        | 3020         | 600            | No           | Admin|
103  | 31122001| M     | 1230       | 300          | 6100           | No           | Sales|
104  | 31122001| f     | 1100       | 3200         | 1600           | No           | Sales|
105  | 31122000| M     | 1100       | 300          | 6010           | No           | Marketing|
106  | 31122000| f     | 1200       | 300          | 600            | No           | Marketing|
107  | 31121999| M     | 1100       | 300          | 600            | No           | Finance|
108  | 31121999| f     | 1200       | 300          | 600            | No           | Finance|
109  | 31121998| M     | 1200       | 300          | 600            | No           | Purchase|
110  | 31121998| f     | 1200       | 300          | 600            | No           | Purchase|
111  | 31121997| M     | 1200       | 300          | 600            | No           | Transport|
112  | 31121997| f     | 1200       | 300          | 600            | No           | Transport|
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `aggregate function` as following:

```
With dataa as
(Select trunc(months_between(sysdate, dob)/12) as age, 
       sum(annual_bonus) as  annual_bonus,
       sum(monthly_bonus) as monthly_bonus,
       sum(quarterly_bonus) as quarterly_bonus,
       Is_permemant
  From employee 
 Where gender = 'M'
 Group by trunc(months_between(sysdate, dob)/12), Is_permemant )
Select coalesce(t1.age, t2.age) as age, 
       t1.annual_bonus, t1.monthly_bonus,t1.quarterly_bonus,
       t2.annual_bonus, t2.monthly_bonus,t2.quarterly_bonus
From dataa t1 full outer join dataa t2
  On t1.age = t2.age
 And t1.Is_permemant = 'Yes' and t2.Is_permemant = 'No'
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. My DOB is in number format as YYYYMMDD, so getting issue with date, rest of the logic is fine

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want conditional aggregation.  I would recommend putting the data in rows and pivoting in the application:

```
select department, is_permenanent, gender,
       floor(months_between(dob, sysdate) / 12) as age, 
       sum(annual_bonus),
       sum(monthly_bonus)
       sum(quarterly_bonus)
from employee
group by department, is_permenanent, gender, 
         floor(months_between(dob, sysdate) / 12);
```

You can pivot the data in SQL using conditional aggregation:

```
select floor(months_between(dob, sysdate) / 12) as age,
       sum(case when department = 'Sales' and
                     is_permanent = 'Yes' and
                     gender = 'F'
                then annual_bonus else 0
            end) as sales_perm_f_annual,
       sum(case when department = 'Sales' and
                     is_permanent = 'Yes' and
                     gender = 'F'
                then annual_monthly else 0
            end) as sales_perm_f_monthly,
       sum(case when department = 'Sales' and
                     is_permanent = 'Yes' and
                     gender = 'F'
                then quarterly_bonus else 0
            end) as sales_perm_f_quarterly_bonus,
        . . . 
from employee
group by floor(months_between(dob, sysdate) / 12);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. saved my whole week :). I am getting one issue. Actually we are saving date as a number in YYYYMMDD format and I am getting "00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: floor(months_between(sysdate, to_date(DOB,'yyyymmdd')) /12) as age  is working but when I try to sort the rows I get "ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month""

Comment: @Glory . . . That sounds like an issue with the data.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, focusing on the issue with the data (i.e. try to simplify the query to find the problem).